# How do I prevent data duplication for Firebase Realtime Database, Web, JavaScript

Tags: javascript, firebase, web, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

This is my database structure for the Users.

[image: This is my database structure]

As you can see in the picture, there are 2 same Identification number are registered successfully.

How can I prevent the "ICNumber"(Identification Number) to be registered more than once?

This is the rule in my RealTime Database:

[image: This is the rule in my RealTime Database]

I tried putting this piece of code but it doesn't seem to work. Is there any way I can do the prevention in my Javascript or any correct way in my Firebase Rule?

Comment: There is no reliable way to prevent duplicate **values** in a JSON structure like the one you have now. It would require that the security rules scan across all nodes, which just doesn't scale. The only way to ensure something is unique in Firebase, is to use those values as the **keys** in the JSON. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/25294478, https://stackoverflow.com/a/57616541, https://stackoverflow.com/a/41113997, and https://stackoverflow.com/a/46056547

Comment: Understood. The links does helps a lot! Thanks ! @FrankvanPuffelen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you can do the following:

```
// Get a reference to the database service
var database = firebase.database();
var dataRetrieved = database.ref('users').child(userId).orderByChild("ICNumber").equalTo("000326141809");
dataRetrieved.on('value', function(snapshot) {
  if(snapshot.exists()){
     // do the required
   }
});
```

You can use a `query` to check if you have an `ICNumber` equal to `000326141809` and then use the method `exists()` to check if it is already in the database

Comment: Thank you so much! Your code works, it detects whether or not the value is already in the database. However, the code still runs my signup() function. Do you have any workaround for this? I've tried: 
break, return, and preventDefault statements, but they don't seem to work

Comment: Just write the signup inside the else and use once instead of on

Comment: Aight man understood! Thanks for the help!